# Errors trying to start nginx after updating Ubuntu

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, nginx-config

I am trying to troubleshoot my nginx and it is not going to well.
I start off by running `sudo systemctl start nginx` and I get

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and so I continue and try `systemctl status nginx.service` to get:

```
Dec 13 00:29:18  systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 13 00:29:18  systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Dec 13 00:29:18 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 13 00:29:18 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

and so I continue to give it a test `sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
resulting in

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "passenger_enabled" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx_aggrigator.conf:164
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I am trying to run this on ubuntu 16.04 if that is any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error say..
`unknown directive "passenger_enabled"`

`nginx_aggrigator.conf:164`

So start by checking this file:
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx_aggrigator.conf

and look at line 164 and find the part where you declare `passenger_enabled` As this is where your error is.

Comment: Thank you.. I have been trying too long to figure this out.